# Even though I have Einops installed in the virtual environment, I was unable to import it

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, einops

Basically, the title, I'm trying to import Einops after installing it through pip, but I can't. I'm using VScode and I'm inside a Jupyter notebook file. As you can see from the bottom of the picture I attached, I have einops installed. I'm in my test virtual environment and, as you can see from the top right, the same environment is selected for the python interpreter. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: einopserror]

Comment: the image is unreadably small.  Nevertheless, i have had this problem before too.... 1. check in the IDLE, 2. check outside of jupyter, 3. check it is installed on the same instance as the version that is being run.

Comment: Will the code run successfully?